# Ocultar tag img do html

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma consulta do banco MySQL em PHP onde eu guardo o caminho no banco e a imagem em uma pasta. A consulta trás a imagem e abaixo um comentário, só que tem comentários sem imagem que exibe a tag `img`. Eu queria um jeito de quando a tag `img` não tiver imagem, não exibir nada.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Não queria que aparecesse a tag quando ela estivesse nula apenas o comentário.

Comment: Coloque como está listando esses comentários. Basta um `IF`para resolver isso.

Answer (score 3):

Se do banco de dados ele retorna NULL quando não tem imagem é só fazer assim =

```
<?php if($img){ ?>
<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>"/>
<?php }else{ ?>
<img src="imgpadrao.jpg">
<?php } ?>
```

Nesse exemplo coloquei uma imagem padrão que você pode colocar, mas se você quiser que não apareça nada, é só tiver o else e deixar só o if.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `file_exists` para verificar se o caminho da imagem é valido, se o mesmo for quer dizer que a imagem existe, se ela não existir você nao precisa mostrar ela na tela exemplo:

```
if (file_exists('caminho/imagem.png')) { // imagem existe
    echo "img src='caminho/imagem.png' alt='img'";
} else { // imagem não existe

}
```

Comment: Acho que a *path* para a imagem não existe, nem tem na base de dados, isso iria causar `file_exists('')` que funcionaria mas não me parece o mais correto. O ideal seria comparar a que vem da base de dados.

Comment: @JorgeB. pelo que entendi ele pega esse path do db para colocar na tag img, sendo assim ele poderia verificar se ela existe, se você fizer `file_exists('')` não entrara na condição de imagem existente você ja fez o teste ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar usar evento onerror, um manipulador de eventos para erros de script de tempo de execução.
Segue um exemplo:

```html
<img 
  src="broken.png" 
  onerror="this.style.display='none'"
/>
```